# Makefile procedure

Tags: linux, makefile, compilation

I have 3 programs **abc.c** **pqr.c** and **xyz.c**
I compile it like this:

```
/usr/bin/gcc -pthread -O2 -fmessage-length=0 -pedantic-errors -std=gnu99 -Werror -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Winit-self -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-aliasing -Wformat=2 -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wno-unused-parameter -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wold-style-definition filename.c -o filename
```

I want to write a makefile to compile the three programs using the above options and produce the three executable files. I have gone through a bunch of tutorials and read the man pages, so please don't ask me to Google it.
If you can give me the direct answer, it would be awesome. Thank you! :)

Comment: At least a couple of those flags are redundant.

Comment: Yeah probably, I'm just doing it this way because we were asked to compile with all these flags.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Comment: Don't read tutorials: I've rarely seen ones that aren't full of errors or at least misinformation.  Man pages are typically _reference_ pages, which require you to have a basic understanding, then provide you with details you may have forgotten.  You should read the GNU make manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this will do it:

```
CC := /usr/bin/gcc
CFLAGS += -pthread -O2 -fmessage-length=0 -pedantic-errors # and so on

.PHONY: all
all: abc pqr xyz
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! Could you please explain what's happening here? What's PHONY? Why do some examples mention rm, clean?

Comment: @Sheetal - If you read the man pages then you know what PHONY does.

Comment: @SheetalKrishna: The `.PHONY:` informs Make that the `all` rule does not actually build a file named "all". It is possible to write rules that do other useful things, like wipe the slate clean. Make has a long learning curve.